# Markdown help page syntax seems off

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, help-center

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Was looking at this page and I noticed the first two markdown examples seem off. There are some strange line breaks added

[image: Code block]

Comment: The code spans section looks broken, too

Comment: Possibly related to [the migration to Common Mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)? I'm guessing not since they've only done Meta so far and this is a Help page.

Comment: Oh, the line breaks are here too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This broke during our .net core port due how the old `@helper` razor code was ported. A fix is rolling out in the next deploy (`rev 2020.6.9.36995` or later)